# Crear un constructor java para varios jtextField que realiza búsqueda en mysql

Tags: java, constructor, jtextfield, listener, addkeylistener

Estoy deseando crear un constructor, lo que hace mi programa es que cada letra que ingresa el operador en el **JTextField** que se llama **nombre**, de manera automática con cada letra que ingresa el operador comienza la búsqueda en la data base y va arrojando los resultados en la tabla de abajo.

**El código me funciona perfecto,** pero mi intensión es crear un constructor para simplificar el código y que ese mismo me sirva para que se ejecuten de los demás **jTextField** que tiene la aplicación.

Abajo le adjunto una imagen y el código.

```
    void buscador(){
    try {
        int row = tablaResultados.getSelectedRow();//Creo el entero con la seleccion de la fila
        conexionDb();
        String selected =(String)nombre.getSelectedText();
        String sql = "SELECT stuff.Emp_Id,stuff.Emp_Name, stuff.Department, "+"certificate.Cert_Code, certificate.Cert_Name,\n"+"certificate.Cert, certificate.Vendor, certificate.Date_Taken, "+ "certificate.Expiry_Date FROM stuff LEFT JOIN certificate"+ " ON stuff.Emp_Id=certificate.Emp_Id  "+ "WHERE " +selected+ " LIKE ? ORDER BY stuff.Emp_Name\n";
        //Statement ejecuto = con.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement  pstmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM persona WHERE nombre LIKE '%" + nombre.getText() + "%'");
        pstmt.setString(1, nombre.getText() + "%");
        actualizarTabla();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Imagen de como funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que cada ves que precise utilizar el **buscador** solo lo llame de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En algún momento debes asignar el evento a los *JTextField* de todas formas, pues lo que se me ocurre seria primero instanciar un *KeyListener* en una variable o implementarlo en una clase y posteriormente agregar el evento con un *for*, **al parecer también es un bloque con la cantidad de código similar a la que tienes pero con la ventaja de que cualquier nuevo *JTextField* que agregues tendrá la funcionalidad automáticamente**, esto ayudaría en el caso de que tengas muchos *JTextField* con la misma funcionalidad.

```
KeyAdapter action = new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
        buscador();
    }
};

// La variabla "miContenedorDeFiltros" es el JPanel que contiene tus JTextfield de filtros
for (Component c : miContenedorDeFiltros.getComponents()) {
    // Solo asignamos el evento a los JTextField
    if (c.getClass().equals(JTextField.class))
        c.addKeyListener(action);
}
```

Esto tendrías que agregarlo en el método principal que se ejecuta al iniciar tu programa, obviamente después de haber agregado los componentes a tu JFrame, en el caso de NetBeans después de la línea `initComponents();` que se encuentra en el constructor.

Es una forma para que no tengas que agregar el método `buscador()` a cada JTextField por separado, al menos por el momento no se me ocurre otra forma, suerte. ;)

> **PD**: Ahora bien agregarlo como constructor mmmm no estoy seguro talvez si crearas tu componente extendiendo de la clase *JTextField* o algo así podría funcionar, pero eso obligaría a que cambies la interfaz utilizando el nuevo componente creado y reemplazándolo por los *JTextField* que ya tienes.

Comment: Hola Israel, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, te consulto, sabrás como puedo hacer casi lo mismo pero con un focusGained? se me ocurre que cuando hagan click en el jTextField haga un if con el nombre del jTextField y dependiendo el nombre corra el buscador que tengo armado.
He intentado adaptar lo que compartiste, pero no logro comprender bien como y donde debo dejar el código y adaptarlo.

Comment: Claro en lugar de usar *KeyAdapter* y la implementación de sus métodos usa : `FocusAdapter focus = new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                // Aqui lo que quieras
            }
        };` y en el for en lugar de `c.addKeyListener(action);` utiliza: `c.addFocusListener(focus);` y con eso haces el evento con el foco para todos los *JTextField*. ;)